# openCV 3D reconstruction using 2 stereo camera pairs

Tags: opencv, camera

I'm experimenting with 2 pairs of stereo cameras (4 pairs), and I'm wondering how to combine the 3d point clouds I get from the 2 pairs of cameras. Basically, I'm successfully getting 2 sets of 3d points from the 2 different pairs of cameras. But, I'm not sure which coordinate frame (the world coordinates) the 3d points are in relative to.

Is it relative to the left camera (the 1st set of image points when calibrating)?

My idea is, if I get the rotation and transform between the two left cameras (let's say it's L_1 and L_2, where L_1 is the left camera for this pair), and then try to transform the 3d points from the R_2 and L_2 pair to the new frame, it would work? But, I'm not sure.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I was actually considering a similar approach for my own project

Comment: I didn't pursue this. But, I believe I found it to be the left camera. As I didn't verify it, I will leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it refers to the left camera, indeed there are some exceptions but in most cases you use the left image as the reference image for disparity calculation. Meaning that the Point cloud is the 3D representation of the left 2D Image. In order to align the Point Clouds you could use the ICP algorithm with the knowledge that the images overlap in some areas.

Take a look here http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/iterative_closest_point.php

Hope this helps, even if its too late